# Create dynamic table - 3 Columns by N-rows?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs

I have a JS object that I'd like to iterate through, creating a three column, N-row, table.

I could have anywhere from 1 to N entries, but always want it a 3colxNrow table.

So far, I can get a single column, N row table:

```
<% for (var person in contacts){ %>
<div>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <h2><u><%= person; %></u></h2>
                    <p id="email"><%= contacts[person]["email"]; %></p>
                    <p id="phoneNumber"><%= contacts[person]["phone number"]; %></p>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <img src=<%= contacts[person]["image"] %> >
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<br>
<% } // for (var person in contacts) %>
```

I'm stuck on how to do this for rows.  The above returns [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPHV2.jpg).  Note it's 7 rows all one  column.

I know I need to somehow loop through and add three `td` within the `tr`, but can't quite get how.

```
...
        <tbody>
            <tr>
               <% for (var person in contacts){ %>
                <td>
                    <h2><u><%= person; %></u></h2>
                    <p id="email"><%= contacts[person]["email"]; %></p>
                    <p id="phoneNumber"><%= contacts[person]["phone number"]; %></p>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <img src=<%= contacts[person]["image"] %> >
                </td>
              <% } // for (var person in contacts) %>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
...
```

This results in a single row, [N columns wide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJSqV.jpg).  Do I need some logic, like `for (var i = 1; i < 4; i++){ ??? }` somewhere?

Comment: i rewtite code, try it. tr - is num of rows, td -is num of column in current row.

Comment: I create array, and divide contacts to arrays with 3 elements. Look my new code.

Comment: May bee this is not good way, but it code should work.

Comment: It's very and very terrible question! You are not would like to think!!

Answer (score 0):

I thing, that for create some rows with 3 column, you can try insert `for` to before `tr`
rebuild your contacts arr:

```
    let arrContacts = [];
    let j = -1, i = 0;
    for(let p in contacts  ){ 
        if(i%3===0){
          arrContacts.push([]);
          j++;  
        }
    arrContacts[j].push(contacts[p]);
   i++;
}
```

and use next template:

```
  <tbody> 
           <% for (var i=0;i<arrContacts.length; i++){ contacts =arrContacts[i] ;%>
                <tr>
                   <% for (var person in contacts){ %>
                    <td>
                        <h2><u><%= person; %></u></h2>
                        <p id="email"><%= contacts[person]["email"]; %></p>
                        <p id="phoneNumber"><%= contacts[person]["phone number"]; %></p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <img src=<%= contacts[person]["image"] %> >
                    </td>
                  <% }  %>
                </tr>
                <% }  %>
            </tbody>
```

Comment: That creates a single column, since for each `person`, it's creating a single row.  [Here's a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEETb.jpg)

Comment: If I switch the `for (var i = 0...` loop with `for (var person in contacts...)` it's getting closer!  I get three columns, but the data repeats instead of doing a unique person per `td`.  [Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXYuJ.jpg)

Comment: Sorry,  I forget rewrite contacts variable.

Answer (score 0):

After writing a 3 column, 4 row HTML table manually, physically printing the HTML out and taking a pen to it...I think I got it!

```
<div>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <% var i = 1; %>
            <% var numCols = 3; %>
            <tr>
                <% for (var person in contacts){ %> 
                    <% console.log("Person: " + person);%>
                    <td>
                        <h2><u><%= person; %></u></h2>
                        <p id="email"><%= contacts[person]["email"]; %></p>
                        <p id="phoneNumber"><%= contacts[person]["phone number"]; %></p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <img src=<%= contacts[person]["image"] %> >
                    </td>
                <% if (i%(numCols)===0 && i > 1){%>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                <% } // (i%(numCols)===0 && i > 1) %> 
                <%i+=1;%>
                <% } // for (var person in contacts) %>                     
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

[Yay!](https://i1.wp.com/killscreen.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/self-high-five-tina-fey.gif?resize=262%2C200&ssl=1)  I think the trick was figuring out the conditional inclusion of `<tr></tr>` to end a row only when we hit our column limit.

(If someone comes across this and has any comments, improvements, warnings, please let me know!)